# Running .NET DLLs via PHP on Linux without COM

Tags: c#, php, .net, linux, wrapper

I've searched a ton of wrappers and questions and none of them have helped my situation.

I've coded many DLLs in `C#` using the `.NET framework` which I need to run on a `Linux` environment through `PHP`.

I found [this](https://github.com/david-garcia-garcia/netphp) which looked promising but it requires the `com_dotnet` extension which is Windows only and thus won't help me on a `Linux` environment.

Any help or pointers on where to go?

Comment: What about .NET Core?

Answer (score 0):

How about making an executable that exposes the DLL functions?

usedll /funcname parm-list